# Error en clase derivada

Tags: c++, poo, clase, objeto, clase-abstracta

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de crear la funcion de `area` **abstracta**. En primer lugar la he declarado abstracta en la case base `forma` del archivo `forma.h`:

```
#ifndef _FORMA_
#define _FORMA_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Forma{
    private:
        int ancho;
        int alto;
    public:
        Forma(int x, int y);
        virtual int area() = 0;
};

#endif
```

y este es `forma.cc`

```
#include "forma.h"
Forma::Forma(int x, int y){
    ancho = x;
    alto = y;
}
```

Ahora he querido completarla en la clase derivada `rectangulo` pero no entiendo bien como tengo que rellenar el constructor. Este es el `rectangulo.h`:

```
#ifndef _RECTANGULO_
#define _RECTANGULO_
#include "forma.h"

class Rectangulo: public Forma{
    public:
        Rectangulo(int x, int y);
        int area();
};

#endif
```

y este el `rectangulo.cc`:

```
#include "rectangulo.h"

Rectangulo::Rectangulo(int x, int y) : Forma(ancho, alto){

}

int Rectangulo::area(){
    return ancho*alto;
}
```

Al compilar `rectangulo` me salen errores e que no puedo acceder por cuestiones de privacidad como:

```
rectangulo.cc: In constructor ‘Rectangulo::Rectangulo(int, int)’:
rectangulo.cc:3:46: error: ‘int Forma::ancho’ is private within this context
 Rectangulo::Rectangulo(int x, int y) : Forma(ancho, alto){
                                              ^~~~~
In file included from rectangulo.h:3:0,
                 from rectangulo.cc:1:
forma.h:8:7: note: declared private here
   int ancho;
```

¿Como soluciono esto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Las variables `ancho` y `alto` pertenecen a `Forma` y son privadas, eso es lo que definiste:

```
class Forma{
    private:
        int ancho; // PRIVADO
        int alto;  // PRIVADO
    public:
        Forma(int x, int y);
        virtual int area() = 0;
};
```

¿No querrías hacer esto?

```
Rectangulo::Rectangulo(int x, int y) : Forma(x, y){
//                         ^      ^          ^  ^
}
```

### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Si pretendes usar el mismo constructor para `Rectangulo` que para `Forma`, puedes traer el constructor de la clase base a la derivada:

  ```
  class Rectangulo: public Forma{
      public:
          // Trae a 'Rectangulo' el constructor de 'Forma'.
          using Forma::Forma;
          int area() { return ancho * alto; }
  };
  ```
- Aunque puedas construir `Rectangulo`, no podrás calcular su área porque las variables `Forma::ancho` y `Forma::alto` siguen siendo privadas, hazlas protegidas:

  ```
  class Forma{
      protected:
          int ancho; // Accesible por clases derivadas, inaccesible en otros casos
          int alto;  // Accesible por clases derivadas, inaccesible en otros casos
      public:
          Forma(int x, int y);
          virtual int area() = 0;
  };
  ```
- Acostúmbrate a usar la lista de inicialización del constructor:

  ```
  Forma::Forma(int x, int y) :
      ancho{x},
      alto{y}
  {}
  ```